# Facebook is throwing "Please specify an image to run with this ad." when trying to create an Ad

Tags: curl, facebook-graph-api, facebook-ads-api, facebook-marketing-api, facebook-business-sdk

Facebook is throwing "Please specify an image to run with this ad." when I try to create adcreative id in turn to create an ad. Its throwing an image error but the image_hash is valid and verified.

I followed the following documentation to create the image hash (which it successfully did) and tried to create a creative Id with it (which did not work)

https://developers.facebook.com/community/threads/427753334468444/

```php
$post = array(
    "name" => "Sample Name",
    "title" => "Sample Title",
    "body" => "Sample Body",
    "object_url" => "www.facebook.com",
    "image_hash" => "47b41fcdaf0bfed48ca3159ec07ffc70",
    "access_token" => "I_added_valid_access_token_here"
);
$ch = curl_init('https://graph.facebook.com/v3.3/act_10***************/adcreatives');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $post);
$resp = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
$respObj = json_decode($resp);
```

The following is what I got as response.

```
code: 100
error_subcode: 1487212
error_user_msg: "Please specify an image to run with this ad."
error_user_title: "Missing Image"
is_transient: false
message: "Invalid parameter"
type: "OAuthException"
```

I also found similar question that was posted on facebook community page 2 days ago but no answers yet. 
https://developers.facebook.com/community/threads/427753334468444/

I have been trying to solve this for couple of days now. I will appreciate any kind of help. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [:"Missing Image","error\_user\_msg":"Please specify an image to run with this ad](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56162535/missing-image-error-user-msgplease-specify-an-image-to-run-with-this-ad)

Answer (score 4):

I have the exact same issue. Found a workaround but it's not good enough for me since it needs a FB post or page to work. But maybe it's good enough for you. Possible workaround is to user `object_story_spec` like so:

```
await account.createAdCreative([], {
  name: "API TESTING",
  object_story_spec: {
    page_id: "34533453534534",
    link_data: {
      image_hash: adImageHash,
      link: "yourlinkhere.com"
    }
  },
  body: adData.Body,
  appsecret_proof
});
```

Comment: i try this one but it's not working. i have an issues on image hash. Have yo any idea how to upload and make image hash. just want to know how to write the path of image.

Answer (score 0):

This worked out for me:

You have to re-upload the images you want to show in your ad.

I mean: Delete the images and upload them again in the window where you set your ad.